# How to make Magento Advanced Search show All products when no Search term is specified?

Tags: magento, advanced-search

Can anyone help me with this problem please?

I use advanced search on magento and it works well, but when I click on "Search" without entering any search terms it gives error or note: "Please specify at least one search term."

I'd like it to show All my products in all categories when I click on "search" without entering any search terms, how is it possible?

Thank you in advance.
Your Help is much appreciated : ))

Regards

P.S. I Use magento 1.5 community version

Answer (score 0):

Under System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search

Change "Minimal Query Length" to 0 and attempt your search again.

I would like to note that wildcard searches can be very taxing depending on the number of attributes that you are searching on, as well the number of products.  This can also depend on LIKE vs FULLTEXT.

As for the second question, this can deal with the Layered Navigation on the same place in admin above.  I would set the number for "Apply Layered Navigation if Search Results are Less Than" equal to the number of products you have in your primary visibility.  Categories are part of layered navigation by default.

Comment: You may have to change how the core search works as well.  Above removes the requirement of minimum parametes but if you do a blank search, you get a SQL Syntax ERROR.  You may need to look into an extension like this one http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Php4u/extension/5999/blast_lucene_seach

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but since i ran into the same problem recently here's how i solved it. The code denying you to be able to search without any parameters lies within the file

```
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Advanced.php
```

in function addFilters() on line 208 (Magento v1.8.1):

```
if ($allConditions) {
        $this->getProductCollection()->addFieldsToFilter($allConditions);
    } else if (!$hasConditions) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->__('Please specify at least one search term.'));
    }
```

So what we want to do is get rid of the Exception beeing thrown. Since we want to never modify any core files we rewrite this class and overload the addFilters() function to catch the Exception, thus enabling an empty advanced search.

Within your module create the file

```
app/code/local/Yournamespace/Yourmodule/Models/Catalogsearch/Advanced.php


class Yournamespace_Yourmodel_Model_Catalogsearch_Advanced extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Advanced {

/**
 * call original addFilters but catch Exception
 * so search WITHOUT search parameters is allowed.
 * 
 * @param array $values
 * @return \Yournamespace_Yourmodel_Model_Catalogsearch_Advanced
 */
public function addFilters($values) {

    try {
        return parent::addFilters($values);
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $ex) {

        return $this;
    }

}
```

}

and rewrite the original advanced search model with your new one:

```
app/code/local/Yournamespace/Yourmodule/etc/config.xml

...
<global>
    <models>
        <catalogsearch>
            <rewrite>
                <advanced>Yournamespace_Yourmodel_Model_Catalogsearch_Advanced</advanced>
            </rewrite>
        </catalogsearch>
    </models>
</global>
...
```

That should do the trick.